# Rendering a txt file on a ROR html.erb page

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a link on one of my html.erb pages which points to a text file. I want to open and display that text file in another html.erb page which has several other things(banners, menubar and other stuff) on it too.

---

html1.erb

### Menubar

<=Link to file1>

---

html2.erb

### Menubar

file1.txt displayed

Other stuff (buttons, checkboxes n stuff)

---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
<%= render :file => '/some/file1.txt' %>
```

Comment: doesn't seem to work...it says : Missing template "filename" with {:handlers=>[:erb, :coffee, :builder], :formats=>[:html], :locale=>[:en]}

Answer (score 2):

```
  <%= render file: 'path/to/text', formats: ['txt'] %>
```

Comment: compile error
file2.html.erb:131: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting tASSOC
...//file1.txt', formats: ['txt'] );@output_buffer.safe...